# Multiple unique constraints in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, datanucleus

Is there a way to specify using JPA that there should be multiple unique constraints on different sets of columns?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person", 
       uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"code", "uid"}))
public class Person {
    // Unique on code and uid
    public String code;
    public String uid;

    // Unique on username
    public String username;

    public String name;
    public String email;
}
```

I have seen a hibernate specific annotation but I am trying to avoid vendor specific solutions as we are still deciding between hibernate and datanucleus.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The `@Table`'s attribute `uniqueConstraints` actually accepts an array of these. Your example is just a shorthand for an array with a single element. Otherewise it would look like:

```
@Table(name="person",  uniqueConstraints={
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"code", "uid"}),
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"anotherField", "uid"})
})
```

Whenever the unique constraint is based only on one field, you can use `@Column(unique=true)` on that column.

Comment: I currently have this annotation, but it seems like Hibernate is not generating the index for the table whether the table already exists (and it's set to update) or if I remove the table and let Hibernate automatically generate it. Am I missing something?